# Holographic microscopy: how 3d structure informations are contained within interference pattern?

Tags: optics, holographic-principle

I am studying holographic miscroscopy and it seems to me that the possibility of constructing the three-dimensional image of an object by irradiating it from one side only is given by the 'registration' of the intensity of the interference pattern formed by the wave that invests it and is scattered by the object and by the same unscattered wave.

This seems to mean that information about the entire external structure of a 3-D object is contained in the way it scatters light.

If I understand: if I illuminate a small sphere with coherent light in such a way as to obtain an interference pattern, is the entire 3D structure of the object contained in this pattern even though the object was irradiated from only one side?

So if on the side not exposed to light I deform the sphere, perhaps by hollowing it out, does the interference pattern I was seeing before change?

Answer (score 0):

> If on the side not exposed to light I deform the sphere, perhaps by hollowing it out, does the interference pattern I was seeing before change?

No. IDK about the microscopy bit, but if the hologram is a traditional laser hologram, then it does *not* encode the entire external structure of a 3-D object. What it encodes is all of the light rays that passed through a window when the hologram was made. And, it reconstructs those rays when  the hologram is properly viewed. Light rays that did not pass through the window (e.g. light rays emanating from the back side of the object where you hollowed it out) are not recorded. They have no effect on the hologram.

The "3D information" is reconstructed by your own brain when it processes the images seen by your two eyes which see the holographic image from two different points of view—exactly as if they were looking at the original object through a window from two different points of view.